# Convert bbox coordinates to geoJSON

Tags: javascript, maps, coordinates, openlayers, geojson

Hello I have a array of coordinates that look something like this: **[14.540536348680394,65.03068471588048,18.945463651319603,66.82731528411952]**

I need to properly display it on my openlayers map but it seems like I must convert the bbox to a valid geoJSON object first. Is there a fuction I can write or a library that can do this for me? Or is there any work arounds using openlayers, I have searched through github but all I could find is libraries that convert geoJSON into bboxes and not the other way around. I am trying to use the bbox to create a shape on a openlayers map with this function and the source is required to be geoJSON.

```
map.addInteraction(
  new Draw({
    type: 'Polygon',
    source: source,
  })
);
```

Comment: You can convert an extent directly to an OpenLayers geometry https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Polygon.html#.fromExtent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `npm install @turf/bbox-polygon` in order to install the `@turf/bbox-polygon` package and transform the bbox that you have with `turf.bboxPolygon(bbox)`.
Here is the npm repository: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@turf/bbox-polygon.

For example:

```
const bboxPolygon = require('@turf/bbox-polygon').default
const bbox = [14.540536348680394,65.03068471588048,18.945463651319603,66.82731528411952]
const polygon = bboxPolygon(bbox)
console.log(polygon)
```